# How to separate cells containing lists in a specific column that has a mixture of strings and lists of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I am trying to organise a pandas data frame in python that has the following pseudo structure (I have altered variable names for ease of understanding):

[Initial_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptEzU.png)

What code is able to split the lists in col_1 so that only individual strings remain for this column, and the count of these individual strings present in col 2 adjusts for the values obtained from rows with lists. i.e. for row 1 above, the values of a from row 2 and row 6 are added to the current 3 to give 'a  |  12' [thats 3 + 6 + 3].

The final data frame should look something like this:

[output_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q8vI.png)

There are 189 rows in this data frame, so I cannot use a code that expects me to identify "a", "b" or even "a,b" for said data when organising it as such. col_1 is either a string or a list as already identified, and col_2 is a count of instances for each value in col_1. This code should also work to create a new individual value if this value occurs in a list but not on its own. i.e for the above if a 7th row had a,e then the a would increase the col_2 count across from "a" by 1, and another row will add to the bottom of the dataframe with "e   |   1" and subsequent occurrences of "e" should get added as described beyond this point.

Comment: Why is 'd' equal to 2 and not 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If structure like this using list in col_1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[['a'],[*'ab'],['c'],[*'bc'],['d'],[*'acd']]
                  ,'col_2':[3,6,1,5,1,3]})
```

Then you can use `explode`, `groupby` and `sum`:

```
df.explode('col_1').groupby('col_1')['col_2'].sum()
```

Output:

```
col_1
a    12
b    11
c     9
d     4
Name: col_2, dtype: int64
```

If co1_1 is a string separated by commas then add this statement ahead:

```
df['col_1'] = df['col_1'].str.split(',')
df.explode('col_1').groupby('col_1')['col_2'].sum()
```

Output:

```
col_1
a    12
b    11
c     9
d     4
Name: col_2, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thank you! that does work exactly as I want it to, but I've realised that col_1 in my cased is actually the index. Is there a quick fix to the code to account for this? thank you

Comment: Yes, `df = df.reset_index()` then use those statements above.